# Ultralytics YOLO8: Capturing more images instead of just one per object

Tags: computer-vision, yolo, yolov8

Currently, I am working on a project that detects license plates within bounding boxes and saves the images in jpg format. The problem arises when the object passes through the bounding boxes, resulting in multiple images being captured.

```
import cv2
import os
import random
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Path to the source video file
video_path = 'sample.mp4'

# Directory to save captured images
output_directory = 'captured_images'
os.makedirs(output_directory, exist_ok=True)

# Create a YOLO object with your trained model
yolo = YOLO('./models/license_plate_detector.pt') # Replace 'best.pt' with the actual path to your trained weights

# Create a VideoCapture object
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

# Check if the video capture is successful
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error: Could not open video.")
    exit()

# Get video properties
frame_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frame_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
aspect_ratio = frame_width / frame_height

# Calculate the dimensions for displaying the frame within the screen
max_width = 1920  # Maximum width for display
max_height = 1080  # Maximum height for display
display_width = min(frame_width, max_width)
display_height = min(frame_height, max_height)
if aspect_ratio > 1:
    display_height = int(display_width / aspect_ratio)
else:
    display_width = int(display_height * aspect_ratio)


cv2.namedWindow("Video with Rectangle", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("Video with Rectangle", display_width, display_height)

# Coordinates and dimensions of the rectangle
x, y, width, height = 2200, 1600, 700, 75

# Flag to track if an image has been captured for the current object
image_captured = False

# Counter to ensure each captured image has a unique name
image_counter = 1

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # Detect objects using your trained YOLO model
    results = yolo(frame)

    
    # Access the detected boxes
    detected_boxes = results[0].boxes[1].xyxy  # Assuming the boxes are stored in results.boxes.xyxy

    for box in detected_boxes:
        center_x = (box[0] + box[2]) / 2
        center_y = (box[1] + box[3]) / 2
 

        if x < center_x < x + width and y < center_y < y + height and not image_captured:

            # Capture the frame portion corresponding to the detected object
            object_frame = frame[int(box[1]):int(box[3]), int(box[0]):int(box[2])]

            # Save the object frame as an image
            image_filename = os.path.join(output_directory, f"captured_object_{image_counter}.jpg")
            cv2.imwrite(image_filename, object_frame)

            image_counter += 1  # Increment the counter for the next image
            image_captured = True  # Set the flag to True to indicate an image has been captured for this object

        elif not (x < center_x < x + width and y < center_y < y + height):
            # Reset the image_captured flag if the object exits the box
            image_captured = False

    # Draw the rectangle on the frame
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + width, y + height), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    resized_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (display_width, display_height))

    # Display the frame
    cv2.imshow("Video with Rectangle", resized_frame)

    # Check for the 'q' key to exit the loop
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release the video capture object
cap.release()

# Close any open windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, I only need one image per object, specifically the one in the center of the bounding box. I have reviewed the Ultralytics documentation but have been unable to find a solution.

Comment: A simple example of the result you need and the result you are getting is preferable. It is unclear what the problem is from the short description and the script.